# How to acess other reference to http://json-schema.org/geojson/geometry.json

Tags: json, jsonschema

There are other references to define geometry.json instead : `http://json-schema.org/geojson/geometry.json ?`

I found this schema, there is an oficial?

```
https://github.com/fge/sample-json-schemas/blob/master/geojson/geometry.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The json-schema.org one lives at http://json-schema.org/example/geo.json, although the schema’s “id” gives http://json-schema.org/geo as the schema’s URI.

As for “official”, that’s debatable. By which I mean we have been debating it at the JSON Schema project, as you can see at https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-org.github.io/issues/171 if you would like to follow the discussion.